# WCF Custom Validator passing parameter and/or find out from which behavior the custom validator is called?

Tags: wcf, x509certificate2

when I call the X509CertificateValidator from the web.config:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehaviour">
          [...]
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="MyX509CertificateValidator, service" />
            </clientCertificate>
           [...] 
        </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

1. Is it possible to pass any parameter/data to the `MyX509CertificateValidator` class?
2. Is it possible to find out, from which behavior (in this case `MyServiceBehaviour`) the `MyX509CertificateValidator` is called (in case if you have several behaviors in the web.config)?